# How to create dynamic object for class in java?

Tags: java, xml, object, reflection

Ex:

```
Element elementInclude1 = doc.createElement("include");
elementMethods.appendChild(elementInclude1);
elementInclude1.setAttribute("name", "T1");

Element elementInclude2 = doc.createElement("include");
elementMethods.appendChild(elementInclude2);
elementInclude2.setAttribute("name", "T2");

Element elementInclude3 = doc.createElement("include");
elementMethods.appendChild(elementInclude3);
elementInclude3.setAttribute("name", "T3");
....
```

In the above example, number of objects(elementInclude1, elementInclude2,..) created are known dynamically.

No of object required are known in run time, using that value iterating in the loop new object created in each iteration. how can I achieve that.

Need to create objects elementInclude1, elementInclude2, elementInclude3,... dynamically while run time

Just for better understanding I used some wrong practice in the below code.

```
String noOfObj = 5;
for(int i = 1; i<=noOfObj; i++)
{
Element elementInclude+**noOfObj** = doc.createElement("include");
elementMethods.appendChild(elementInclude+**noOfObj**);
elementInclude+**noOfObj**.setAttribute("name", "T1");
}
```

Comment: Use an array...

Comment: Do you even need separate reference variables? Are you using them outside the loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create objects at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938482/how-do-i-create-objects-at-runtime)

Comment: See: [Oracle Java Tutorials - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int noOfObj = 5;
    //create an array to hold elements
    Element[] elememtsArray = new Element[noOfObj];

    for(int i = 1; i<=noOfObj ; i++){

        Element element = doc.createElement("include");
        elememtsArray[i] = element;
    }
```

Alternatively, if the number of elements is un known, use list

```
    ArrayList<Element> elementsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i<= 6 ; i++){//6 is an arbitrary num for demo

        Element element = doc.createElement("include");
         elementsList.add(element);
    }
```

Alternatively, if you need the reference name, use map

```
    Map<String, Element> elementsMap= new HashMap();
    for(int i = 1; i<=7 ; i++){ //7 is an arbitrary num for demo

        Element element = doc.createElement("include");
        String elementName = "elementInclude"+ i;
        elementsMap.put(elementName, element);
    }
```

Comment: I am glad it helps